# Superman computes pi

Tags: dc, comics, superman, episode-identification

My father remembers an old Superman comic in which Lois Lane is kidnapped and her return is conditioned on Superman computing the last digit of pi (you know, 3.1415926535...) Or perhaps this is just to keep him busy. I think in the end he succeeds.

Is this known? Any reference?

Comment: If he did succeed, would have toppled a lot of Math since Pi is a transcendental number.  Infinitely long, no repetition.  It has no 'last digit'.  Will be interesting to see if anyone knows of such an issue.

Comment: I've found someone referring to [Superman calculating Pi to one trillion digits](http://dawnandnocturnes.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/the-gospel-of-superman-2/), but does not cite a reference.

Comment: That's so evil it's funny! It's not widely put out that Superman is at par level of Genius (though by how much, I don't know) and has made attempts to use his intellect to help Earth and Humanity (such as curing cancer). If I had to fight Superman, mindgames might not be a good choice, since he has a rather elevated IQ.

Comment: Hell, Supes could just guess.  He's got a 1 in 10 chance, and if he's wrong, how will they know?

Comment: Do you happen to know when your father might have read it? It might help the search.

Comment: @phantom42: Not a clear idea. If he read it, that was in Mexico and must have been 50s to 60s. He could also have seen it in passing (didn't care for comics then) while in the US at the beginning of the 70s, but that is unlikely.

Comment: And besides, I would think Supes would use his time more wisely than figuring out an irrational number. I mean, circles are round; problem solved. Can we go back to punching Cyborg now?

Comment: I remember a comic in which Superman or Superboy was asked to compute the entire decimal expansion of pi (or some other irrational number). He was applying for admission to a college or maybe for a job. The person who asked him knew he was asking for something impossible, but he wanted to turn down his application. Superboy started writing the digits on billboards which embarassed the person who asked him so he let him quit.

Comment: I don't think this is your story, but there was a special comic that was a long ad for TRS-80 home computers by Radio Shack.  At one point in that story, Superman was relying on a couple of kids computing numbers for him using the TRS-80 computer.

Comment: Sounds like something from the Silver Age, when Superman had to power to Make Up Power When Convenient, including (I swear to god) Super-Mathematics, as seen here: http://superdickery.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=36&Itemid=53&limitstart=1 and as pointed out, Super Mathematics apparently calculates things an order of magnitude higher than regular math (perhaps that's what makes it super?).

Comment: If this was in an issue at some point, it would have to be an older one, back past the point when we discovered that Pi didn't really end.  There was a time when the scientific community was searching for the end of Pi.

Comment: @HellothisisMary: That π was irrational was [proved on 1761](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational), so that way predates any Superman story.

Comment: @rodrigo: Just because we considered it infinite and irrational doesn't mean we weren't still trying to compute the exact value of Pi as late as the forties.

Comment: @HellothisisMary: Because pi is irrational, it has no "exact value" in a digital representation. Computer scientists in the 1940s were well aware of this. What people have done, and continue to do, is compute pi to as many digits as possible as a kind of stunt to show off the power of computers. As of December 2013, the record appears to be [12.1 trillion digits](http://www.numberworld.org/misc_runs/pi-12t/), but there will never, ever be a "last digit" or "exact representation" of pi.

Comment: Rolled back another "dc movies" tag. The question *specifically* states that they're looking for a comic.

Comment: @HellothisisMary we definitely weren't 'trying to compute the exact value of Pi as late as the forties'. Some people were trying to compute *a more exact* value, which is an entirely different thing that *the* exact value.

Answer (score 5):

I've found a couple of instances where Superman does maths on a blackboard. Neither of them seem to fit the plotline you've described but I'm hoping it jogs a memory:

**[Superman V1 - #224 - "Beware the Super-genius Baby"](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_224)**
[image]
The entire comic is set in a fantasy world where Lois and Clark have had a kid. The super-baby is much smarter than he is.

**[The Computers that Saved Metropolis](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_in_The_Computers_That_Saved_Metropolis)**
[image]
This was from a set of three comics created in order to market Radio Shack's TRS-80 computers. Superman is targeted with a "dumb-ray" that makes him act like a moron.

Comment: It's not the answer.. But, I liked the comic stripes.. :)