# Does anyone know where I can find a Batman-Wolverine crossover?

Tags: marvel, dc, batman, episode-identification, wolverine

I have seen some mentions of a comic crossover, in which DC Comics Batman meets and possibly fights Marvel's Wolverine. Does anyone know where this is?

Comment: As worded, this comes across as a list/recommendation question. I feel like there *is* a valid question in here (similar to [Superman Computes Pi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40716/superman-computes-pi)) - that can, and should, be reworded as a story identification question.

Answer (score 4):

After the Marvel vs DC comics Jack B Nimble mentions there is an **Amalgam** of Batman and Wolverine: [The Dark Claw](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Logan_Wayne_%28Amalgam_Universe%29)!

I think there are only two issues of that but if I remember correctly they're actually pretty fun stories, with Sabertooth and Joker having merged to become The Hyena. *Though I'm afraid that's as close as we get to a Bats and Wolvie crossover.*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no such match up that is official. In the [DC vs Marvel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_vs._Marvel) limited series Wolverine goes against Lobo, and Batman goes against Captain America.

Super Power Beat Down did a matchup between Batman and Wolverine

And Pierre Desgranges and Atomic Production did something similar.

http://robot6.comicbookresources.com/2011/05/the-dark-knight-vs-wolverine-in-stylish-batman-deliverance/

Comment: im not sure if this is what i was looking for, but its something `+1`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I've read a Wolverine-Star Trek crossover comic (it was bad) but I don't remember coming across a Batman-Wolverine one. A bit of searching found [Dark Claw](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Claw).

You could also search for fanfic materials. [Rule 34](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleThirtyFour)¹ will apply, so be careful.

---

¹ Warning - TV Tropes link! Your productivity will suffer.

Comment: Dark Claw is the result of the DC vs Marvel limited series crossover.

Comment: correction: fanfic is at least 25% porn... [from same site](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SelfFanservice)

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight - just 25%? You need to find better sources of fanfic, clearly <g>

Comment: @DVK i wanted to say 75%, but tried to stay on the safe side :P